# Eliminating "Exists Unique" in Lean 3

Tags: lean3, automated-theorem-proving, axiom-of-choice

In Lean 3, similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4370451/existence-elimination-in-lean-3), I want to exhibit a witness of $x$ of $P(x)$, given that $\exists x,P(x)$. The difference is that I can also prove $\exists! x,P(x)$, so there is exactly 1 element satisfying $P(x)$. Is the Axiom of Choice ("classical.some") still needed? If not, how would I obtain a witness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in general you do need the axiom of choice (or a derivative theorem).  Unique choice doesn't follow from the base rules of Lean, unlike ZF and univalent foundations.  Also, Lean is very minimal with its selection of available axioms and most Lean projects (especially the main math library `mathlib`) use all three of them, including [`classical.choice`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/init/classical.html#classical.choice).  There is no separate unique choice axiom in Lean (unlike Coq's [`unique_choice`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.ClassicalUniqueChoice.html#unique_choice)).  (You could define one of course, but it isn't in the spirit of Lean. Even the law of excluded middle [`classical.em`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/init/classical.html#classical.em) is defined in terms of the axiom of choice.)

Nonetheless, there are various derivative theorems and tactics for this setting.  In base Lean, you can use the theorems in [`classical`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/init/classical.html).

Now, not all settings need the full power of the axiom of choice.    If your type is enumerable and your predicate marked [`decidable`](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/type_classes.html#decidable-propositions), then you can just search for the answer, and since you know an answer exists, you know your search will terminate.  Therefore, no special axioms are needed.  This (I believe) is what is behind [`nat.find`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/init/data/nat/lemmas.html#nat.find), [`fintype.choose`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/data/fintype/basic.html#fintype.choose), and [`finset.choose`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/data/finset/basic.html#finset.choose).  (This has nothing in particular to do with unique choice.)

Also, if you are trying to just use the existential to prove a proposition, you don't need choice to do so.  You can use the tactics [`cases`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/tactics.html#cases), or in mathlib, [`obtain`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/tactics.html#obtain) and [`rcases`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/tactics.html#rcases).  Also, for unique choice you could use the theorem [`exists_unique.elim`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/init/logic.html#exists_unique.elim). (The technical details are that most propositions like `Exists` can only eliminate into other propositions (small elimination) and not into regular types (large elimination).  The details are spelled out [in these notes](https://lean-forward.github.io/logical-verification/2018/41_notes.html).)

You can find more in depth discussions on unique choice on Zulip [here](https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/113489-new-members/topic/.E2.9C.94.20turn.20.22exists.20and.20is.20unique.22.20into.20a.20function/near/290820767) and [here](https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/113489-new-members/topic/.E2.9C.94.20The.20king.20of.20France/near/252510377).  Also, see [the section on choice in TPIL](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/axioms_and_computation.html?highlight=choice#choice).

Comment: I am trying to formalize ZFC in Lean, and I easily proved the empty set exists but when I tried to define the empty set I had to use classical.some and was forced to "noncomputable" it. Is there a way to get rid of this?

Comment: @ZongshuWu: ZFC does not have a constant for the empty set, it only has one binary relation symbol $\in$.

Comment: @ZongshuWu I think it would depend on your exact structures. If for example, like Andre is (maybe?) suggesting, you use Lean structures to define models of ZFC where the axioms are exactly the usual ZFC axioms, then I think to define the empty set, you will need choice. The same would happen if you define say groups with just the multiplication symbol. You would need choice to define the group identity and inverse.

Comment: One solution is not to state the ZFC axioms in the usual way, but to add some additional fields to your structure like the empty set, the comprehension function, pairs, an infinite set, etc.  Basically every axiom which asserts that something exists, add that to your structure along with an axiom that it behaves as expected.

Comment: Also, you may want to look at previous projects which build models of ZFC set theory in Lean 3:[The flypitch project to prove the independence of CH](https://github.com/flypitch/flypitch) and [set_theory.zfc library in mathlib](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/set_theory/zfc/basic.html).

Comment: Also I don’t see a lot of problems with choice and `noncomputable` for models of ZFC.  To construct any model of ZFC you need choice anyway and no model of ZFC (or even ZF) can be computable.

Comment: I have looked at the set_theory.zfc. Not what I want. I used the axioms exclusively, with no "construction" whatsoever. Oh well, then I guess "noncomputable" is unavoidable.

Comment: @ZongshuWu Since you do not want "construction whatsoever", why do you want to construct the empty set? Isn't the existence of an empty set good enough?

Comment: @Trebor, constructing the empty set is just a convenience so that I can write it down when I formalize theorems, otherwise they will just be a million symbols long. My point is that I don't want to actually construct a model of ZFC, I just start with the axioms.

Comment: @ZongshuWu I would be surprised if it really is much longer (1.05× longer is my hard upper bound). If you are only proving propositions then you can extract the witness in the proof IIRC. Would you mind showing me where exactly it will be a million symbols long? My bet is that this is a common misconception that doesn't really hold in type theories.

Comment: @Trebor, The Axiom of Infinity. Since I have to declare all axioms before I can do anything, the axiom reads
∃ (I : V), (∃ e, (∀ x, x ∉ e) ∧ e ∈ I) ∧ ∀ x, x ∈ I → ∃ y, (∀ z, z ∈ y ↔ (z ∈ x ∨ z = x)) ∧ y ∈ I, but if I define notation, then it becomes ∃ (I : V), ∅ ∈ I ∧ ∀ x, x ∈ I → x ∪ {x} ∈ I.